# opamがstack overflowを吐くようになってしまいました。

Tags: ocaml

opamでいろいろパッケージをインストールしていたのですが、パッケージのインストールは成功したものの、その後opamが Stack overflow を返すようになってしまいました。何か解決方法はありますでしょうか。

```
$ opam update

=-=- Updating package repositories =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
[default] synchronized from https://opam.ocaml.org
Fatal error:
Stack overflow
Backtrace:
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "pervasives.ml", line 214, characters 22-31
  Called from file "solver/opamSolver.ml", line 330, characters 8-44
  Called from file "client/opamClient.ml", line 805, characters 6-356
  Called from file "client/opamClient.ml", line 1211, characters 12-34
  Called from file "core/opamFilename.ml", line 324, characters 12-15
```

新たなパッケージのインストールを使用としても同様のエラーがでます。opam switchはできます。

環境は以下のとおりです。

- opam 1.2.2
- OCaml 4.02.3
- Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 3):

私はこういう状況におちいったことがないのですが、`opam update`するとその後にupgradeできるかチェックするフェーズがあります。そこでopam内部にあるバージョン条件を解く制限ソルバがスタックを消費して死んでいる状態ですね。

例えば、外部のソルバを使ってはどうでしょうか: 詳しい方法は http://cudf-solvers.irill.org/index.html にあります。

https://github.com/ocaml/opam/issues/2544 によるとそういう状況は知られているようで、そこでも外部ソルバを使うように勧められています。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。外部のソルバーを使うとか私にはちょっと自信なかったので、ためせていません。

Comment: ただし、opam switch で別の環境に切り替えると問題は起こらないのでとりあえず別にswitchして回避しました。

Comment: 内部組み込みのソルバの出来は残念ながらあまりよくありません。`opam reinstall hogehoge` とすると、同じバージョンのソフトウェアをインストールしなおすだけなのに、関係するたくさんのパッケージがダウングレードされると言われます。`opam`の人達は常に外部ソルバ使ってほしいと言っているようです。